# Producer-consumer for 10+ processes reading from the same table

Tags: oracle, parallel-processing, oracle11gr2

I have table like in this [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/04001/1/0):

```
CREATE TABLE buffor_table
    ("ID" int, "NAME" varchar2(10), "STATUS" varchar2(10))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO buffor_table ("ID", "NAME", "STATUS")
         VALUES (1, 'something1', 'PROCESSING')
    INTO buffor_table ("ID", "NAME", "STATUS")
         VALUES (2, 'something2', 'WAITING')
    INTO buffor_table ("ID", "NAME", "STATUS")
         VALUES (3, 'something3', 'WAITING')
    INTO buffor_table ("ID", "NAME", "STATUS")
         VALUES (4, 'something4', 'FINISHED')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_BUFFOR_WAITING AS
  SELECT ID, NAME, STATUS FROM BUFFOR_TABLE
  WHERE STATUS = 'WAITING';
```

I need to have some process/job that will for every minute look for rows in "WAITING" status, then for each one span new sub-process to do the job.

I want to offer this solution; create 10 chains (using Oracle Chains) and set up them to execute parallel and as oracle job fired every minute. The Chain logic will be simple:

1. `select id into id_to_process from v_buffor_waiting where rownum < 2 for update;`
2. `update buffor_table set status='PROCESSING' where id = id_to_process;`
3. `commit`
4. do some long calculations, etc
5. simple update/commit operation for setting status into `FINISHED`

I know that a `NO_DATA_FOUND` exception can be throw at position 1. It will be handled as "nothing to do".

My steps 1-3 are for locking only one row (when starting 10 chains parallel I want that each chain will process only one row) and steps 1-3 will be like atomic operation - no other process will have the same ID to process.

Is there a standard approach to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical scheduling scenario. Oracle is very good at running SQL queries and updates in parallel, but this can be harder. I've worked in the past on three different schedulers using Oracle as backend.

Some recommendations from my experiences:

- Use a table, not a view since views have no on-lock trigger (you already do this well).
- Use 'for update' with a timeout to avoid ever lasting locks.
- Remember that Oracle in a multiprocessor system uses spinning instead of sleeping to acquire database locks.
- Avoid 'dining philisophers' problems by making sure that all concurrent processes follow the same order. This avoids dead locks.
- Add sleeps after each try to acquire a lock.
- Ensure that after incidents (such as database being shut down) the locks are released. For instance by registering in the `update` statement also the sid/serial# in buffor_table. And releasing locks automatically.
- Ensure that after a chain crashes, the locks are released. Similarly using sid/serial# or something alike to detect whether the consuming process is still alive.
- As an alternative, look at `dbms_lock`. It has some limitation, but might offer a simpler but less flexible solution.

I hope this answers your question. When not, please extend your question or let me know what you are missing.